# Syntax for Multi-Option Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, syntax

ASP.NET 4.0, Web forms, C#, SQL

I pretty much have something similar to a search form that you'd see on a dating website. Multiple drop down boxes, and each ddbox has specific values as well as an "any" value. I can't think of an easy way to create this syntax outside of the below example with a lot of else if statements in the c# code behind button click event:

```
if
= && = && =
else if<br/>
= && = && !=
else if<br/>
= && != && != 
else if<br/>
!= && = && !=
```

... here is the same sequence with selected values

```
if
Any && Any && Any
else if
Any && Any && Not Any
else if
Any && Not Any && Not Any
else if
Not Any && Any && Not Any
```

This goes on until I cycle through all scenarios. On button click the code behind would take the selected values and decide which query to perform. What seems to be causing the headache is the value "any" in the ddbox. Is there a preferred way to structure the c# or sql syntax to reduce the number of else if's?

Let me know if this makes sense or if you need more info.

Comment: if you want to have the database return the results in a timely manner, there are many considerations to make in your quest for index usage.  Your journey should begin reading this: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). This is a SQL Server article (you seem to be in the "Microsoft" environment). If you are going after "generic" SQL to work on any database, good luck there using "generic" SQL and getting good performance with searches like these as your tables grow.  It is hard to tune/optimize a query without knowing the database.

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like this:

```
create procedure usp_search (
    @param1 varchar(50) = null
   ,@param2 carchar(50) = null
) as
begin
    select field1
          ,field2
          ,field3
          ,fieldN
      from table t with(nolock)
     where ((@param1 is null) or (t.fieldX == @param1))
       and ((@param2 is null) or (t.fieldY == @param2))
end
```

then on your client you do like

```
//code
var connection = new SqlConnection("connection_string");
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "usp_Search";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVariable1)) || (stringVariable2.ToLower().Equals("any"))) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
} else {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = stringVariable1;
}
if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVariable2)) || (stringVariable2.ToLower().Equals("any"))) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
} else {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = stringVariable2;
}
// code
```

Something along these lines... this way your search query can retrieve filtered or unfiltered results.. of course you would have to watch for some pitfalls of this type of query

**Edit:** The same thing done only in the C# code would be something like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("select field1 ,field2, field3, fieldN ");
sb.Append("from table t with(nolock) ");
sb.Append("where ((@param1 is null) or (t.fieldX == @param1))");
sb.Append("and ((@param2 is null) or (t.fieldY == @param2))");

var connection = new SqlConnection("connection_string");
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = sb.ToString();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVariable1)) || (stringVariable2.ToLower().Equals("any"))) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
} else {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = stringVariable1;
}
if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVariable2)) || (stringVariable2.ToLower().Equals("any"))) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = DBNull.Value;
} else {
    command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlType.VarChar, 50).Value = stringVariable2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot. I was thinking along the parameter line but wasn't sure what to do about the "Any" feature of the query. Will most likely get to testing this tomorrow...

Comment: Unfortunately there's not a lot of options when it comes to filtering, ugly `if` statements everywhere, but something along these lines should work. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest looking into using an ORM in your next project as dynamic sql has a lot of these kinds of caveats when it comes to application design.

That said, the way I handled this was to place any optional search terms inside parenthesis so I could do this:

(SomeField = 'Blah' OR 1=1)

Bear in mind, I'm not saying this is a good solution but it does allow you to cut down on the number of nested statements because you can construct your SQL statement sequentially.

Consider the following code:

```
SQL = "SELECT CompanyName, CompanyState FROM Companies WHERE ";
SQL += "(CompanyName = '" & CompanyName & "' " + (CompanyName == "AnyKey" ? " OR 1=1" : "") + ") ";
SQL += "(CompanyState = '" & CompanyState & "' " + (CompanyState == "AnyKey" ? " OR 1=1" : "") + ") ";
```

Again, I stress this isn't supposed to be considered good. I've since moved on to ORMs so I don't have this issue anymore. And as always, be sure to sanitize your user input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try tomorrow also and see how it goes - and will definitely look int ORM!

Comment: At work I use LLBLGen and it does the job great, but we had to implement a massive data layer around it.. if the project is large, research many ORMs and how you work with them before you make the decision